# Object from External ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, storyboard

I have StoryBoard in external `ResourceDictionary`. I can retrive this storyboard succesfuly, but I cant sign for `Completed` event

I got **InvalidOperationException** :

> Specified value of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'
>   must have IsFrozen set to false to
>   modify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a clone of the `StoryBoard` and modify that instance.

```
Storyboard storyboard = FindResource...Clone();
storyboard.Completed += handler...
```

You can also call `Freeze` if using the [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) pattern; however once you call `Freeze` you can not reverse the `IsFrozen` state back to false.